# FIWARE IoTAgent-ul and IoTAgent-json error log

Tags: http, docker-compose, mqtt, fiware, fiware-orion

there are two existing IoT agents in our application, one is ***iotagent-ul(over HTTP)***, another is ***lwm2m-iotagent(over HTTP)***. Recently in order to integrate new sensors, I need to add a new ***iotagent-json(over MQTT)***. After bringing up the system, there is some strange error log as I pasted at the end:

(1) ***iotagent-ul*** is over `HTTP`, `IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT` is not defined in iotagent-ul, just use the default value `HTTP`, but iotagent-ul always complains that "`Couldn't connect with MQTT broker`" and "`Error: Callback was already called`", why will iotagent-ul try to connect MQTT broker?

(2) ***iotagent-json*** is defined with `IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT=MQTT`, but it also reports a error for `IOTAJSON.AMQP.Binding`, should I just ignore it?

These containers can run up, but an endless error log is thrown out in the console. BTW, before adding the new iotagent-json, these two previous iotagent-ul and lwm2m-iotagent can work properly.
Could you help me view the error info and the IoT agents definition in yml? Any comments are appreciated, thank you very much.

**1 The services defined in docker-compose.yml file:**

```
# IoT Agents ##################################################################
  iot-agent-ul:
    image: fiware/iotagent-ul
    hostname: iot-agent-ul
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-ul
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "4041"
      - "7896"
    ports:
      - "4041:4041"
      - "7896:7896"
    environment:
      - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion" # name of the context broker to update context
      - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026" # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - "IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2" # NGSI version to use
      - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041" # port for devices provisioning
      - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb" #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=ERROR" #The log level of the IoT Agent
      - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true" # whether to include or not the timestamp
      - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db" # The host name of MongoDB
      - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017" # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul" # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=7896" # The port used for device traffic over HTTP
      - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent-ul:4041" # URL of the agent
      - "IOTA_AUTOCAST=true" # autocasting of values into NGSI standard

  iot-agent-lwm2m:
    image: hopu/lwm2m-iotagent:observe-and-read
    hostname: iot-agent-lwm2m
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-lwm2m
    expose:
      - "4042"
      - "5683"
    ports:
      - "4042:4042"
      - "5683:5683/udp"
    environment:
      - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion" # name of the context broker to update context
      - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026" # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4042" # port for devices provisioning
      - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb" # whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=ERROR" #The log level of the IoT Agent
      - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true" # whether to include or not the timestamp
      - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db" # The host name of MongoDB
      - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017" # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentlwm2m" # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=5683" # The port used for device traffic over HTTP
      - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent-lwm2m:4042" # URL of the agent
      - "IOTA_AUTOCAST=true" # autocasting of values into NGSI standard
    volumes:
      - "./iota-lwm2m/config.js:/opt/iota-lwm2m/config.js"
      - "./iota-lwm2m/omaRegistry.json:/opt/iota-lwm2m/omaRegistry.json"
      - "./iota-lwm2m/omaInverseRegistry.json:/opt/iota-lwm2m/omaInverseRegistry.json"
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - mongo-db
      - orion
    networks:
      - default

  iot-agent-json:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json:latest
    hostname: iot-agent-json
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-json
    depends_on:
        - mongo-db
        - mosquitto
    expose:
        - "4043"
        - "7896"                          # No traffic,7896 is the http listening port for sensors
    ports:
        - "4043:4043"
        - "7898:7898"                     # No traffic
    environment:
      - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion"              # name of the context broker to update context
      - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026"               # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4043"            # port for devices provisioning
      - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb"      # Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"            # The log level of the IoT Agent
      - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true"             # whether to include or not the timestamp
      - "IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2"         # NGSI version to use
      - "IOTA_AUTOCAST=true"              # autocasting of values into NGSI standard
      - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo-db"        # The host name of MongoDB
      - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017"           # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentjson"      # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=7898"             # The port used for device traffic over HTTP
      - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:4043" # URL of the agent
      - "IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE=/iot/json" # IOTA_PROVIDER_URL, the default path the IoT Agent uses listening for JSON measures over HTTP.
      - "IOTA_MQTT_HOST=mosquitto"        # MQTT broker service
      - "IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883"             # MQTT service port
      - "IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT=MQTT"     # ---
      - "IOTA_MQTT_USERNAME=myusername"
      - "IOTA_MQTT_PASSWORD=mypassword"
    networks:
        - default
```

**2 After docker containers start-up, some error log printed out:**

```
fiware-iot-agent-ul | time=2022-08-23T09:19:32.404Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=650cc5a7-e0b0-406a-bb7d-84db422bb0e3 | trans=650cc5a7-e0b0-406a-bb7d-84db422bb0e3 | op=IOTAUL.AMQP.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672 | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent-ul | time=2022-08-23T09:19:32.405Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=650cc5a7-e0b0-406a-bb7d-84db422bb0e3 | trans=650cc5a7-e0b0-406a-bb7d-84db422bb0e3 | op=IoTAgentNGSI.ContextServer | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=GLOBAL-002: Couldn't connect with MQTT broker: {"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":1883} | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent-ul | time=2022-08-23T09:19:32.409Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.DomainControl | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=Error: Callback was already called.
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at /opt/iotaul/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:32
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.<anonymous> (/opt/iotaul/lib/bindings/MQTTBinding.js:375:17)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.emit (node:events:539:35)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.emit (node:domain:475:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.streamErrorHandler (/opt/iotaul/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:460:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
fiware-iot-agent-ul |   domainThrown: true
fiware-iot-agent-ul | } | comp=IoTAgent

fiware-iot-agent-ul | time=2022-08-23T09:19:33.425Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=n/a | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=GLOBAL-002: Couldn't connect with MQTT broker: {"errno":-111,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":1883} | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent-ul | time=2022-08-23T09:19:33.426Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=n/a | trans=n/a | op=IoTAgentNGSI.Global | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=An unexpected exception has been raised. Ignoring: Error: Callback was already called.
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at /opt/iotaul/node_modules/async/dist/async.js:969:32
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.<anonymous> (/opt/iotaul/lib/bindings/MQTTBinding.js:375:17)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.emit (node:events:539:35)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at MqttClient.emit (node:domain:475:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.streamErrorHandler (/opt/iotaul/node_modules/mqtt/lib/client.js:460:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at Socket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
fiware-iot-agent-ul |     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) | comp=IoTAgent

fiware-iot-agent-json | time=2022-08-23T09:19:35.473Z | lvl=INFO | corr=76c65807-e6f8-4ed0-ab3c-ead581e9d6bd | trans=76c65807-e6f8-4ed0-ab3c-ead581e9d6bd | op=IOTAJSON.MQTT.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=connected | comp=IoTAgent
fiware-iot-agent-json | time=2022-08-23T09:19:35.486Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=76c65807-e6f8-4ed0-ab3c-ead581e9d6bd | trans=76c65807-e6f8-4ed0-ab3c-ead581e9d6bd | op=IOTAJSON.AMQP.Binding | from=n/a | srv=n/a | subsrv=n/a | msg=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5672 | comp=IoTAgent
```

Comment: For MQTT/AMPQ - the absence of `config.mqtt` in the configuration disables the MQTT - at least in the code. So theoretically an appropriately configured `config.js` could be injected. However the configService line 154 always sets up a config with mqtt and apmq objects. This plus the fact that the default `config.js` holds default values means that it is currently impossible not to enable AMQP and MQTT. I think this is a bug to be fixed - PR in progress [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-json/pull/685)

Comment: @Jason Fox, Thank you for your explanation. 
In my docker-compose.yml, I added the below lines to iot-agent-ul's environment, which uses UL-over-HTTP :
`- "IOTA_MQTT_DISABLED=true"
- "IOTA_AMPQ_DISABLED=true"`.
**But the same error logs are still there.**
I saw this bug has been fixed in _github source code_, does this bug been fixed in _'image: fiware/iotagent-ul'_, maybe the docker image has not been updated?

Comment: In addtion , for the fiware/iotagent-ul, how can I login the container? I tried /bin/sh, /bin/bash and /bin/ash in portainer with user=root, but all of the connection are failed.

Comment: It depends on the flavour of the image - `/bin/sh` should work with the default debian based image `fiware/iotagent-ul:x.y.z`, `/bin/sh` **won't** work with `fiware/iotagent-ul:x.y.z-distroless` since the distro containing the bash shell has been removed. Distroless is lightweight, but not useful to use in a dev environment when you want the flexibility to enter the container. Distroless is more secure, but should not be used when debugging for obvious reasons.

Comment: _", maybe the docker image has not been updated?"_ - correct. The PR in question is still **open** and hasn't been accepted into mainline yet. When a release occurs, a new Docker image will be created by [Telefónica](https://hub.docker.com/u/telefonicaiot). The [FIWARE](https://hub.docker.com/u/fiware) clone usually lags the developer's release by a few days thereafter.

Comment: It looks like the polling error has been fixed in the latest 1.24 and 1.25 releases of the IoT Agents